# Debugging Python 3 Runtime Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, runtime-error

So I've been working on a school project, and this one function has been giving me a lot of trouble. It takes an object in a dictionary from index (x, y), and moves it to a new index. I'm getting a RuntimeError every time I run it, and I assume it's because I'm adding a new index to the dictionary, but I don't know how to solve the problem. An enemy in the enemydict has the 'leap' attribute (an integer) and is at index (xlocation, ylocation). Heres the code;

```
def moveEnemies(self):
    keys = self.enemydict.keys()
    for key in keys:
        leap = self.enemydict[key].leap

        if self.enemydict[key].attacked == False:
            self.enemydict[key].counter -= 1

        if self.enemydict[key].counter <= 0 and self.enemydict[key].attacked == False:

            self.enemydict[key].counter = self.enemydict[key].turncount
            for i in range(leap):

                option = random.randint(0, 9)
                if option == 1:
                    goingTo = [key[0]+1,key[1]]

                elif option == 2:
                    goingTo = [key[0]+1,key[1]+1]

                ...

                elif option == 8:
                    goingTo = [key[0]-1,key[1]-1]
                else:
                    goingTo = key

                if self.getMapSquare(goingTo[1], goingTo[0]) == '#':
                    self.genSquare(goingTo[1], goingTo[0])
                try:
                    self.enemydict[(goingTo[0], goingTo[1])] = self.enemydict[key]
                    self.enemydict[key] = ' '
                except: #this fixed a smaller problem, but it just gave the runtimeerror
                    pass

                continue
```

And here's the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/cp1-workspace/semester-1 - Python/unit-06 - oop and game/p1-pyzork/not_quite_zork/game.py", line 442, in <module>
    gm.mainloop()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/cp1-workspace/semester-1 - Python/unit-06 - oop and game/p1-pyzork/not_quite_zork/game.py", line 423, in mainloop
    self.moveEnemies()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/cp1-workspace/semester-1 - Python/unit-06 - oop and game/p1-pyzork/not_quite_zork/game.py", line 365, in moveEnemies
    for key in keys:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Can you paste the full error text?  The error should tell you what the problem is and the line number where the error was raised.

Comment: It should be there now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means just what it says: you have changed the size of a dictionary while iterating over it.

That happens in this line:

```
self.enemydict[(goingTo[0], goingTo[1])] = self.enemydict[key]
```

This adds a new value to the `self.enemydict`, and it's inside the loop where you iterate over that dictionary:

```
keys = self.enemydict.keys()
for key in keys:
```

Here's a simplified example in the Python console:

```
>>> d = { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B' }
>>> d
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
>>> keys = d.keys()
>>> for k in keys:
...     print( k )
...     if k == 'a':
...         d['c'] = 'C'
...
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Note that even though we've assigned `d.keys()` into its own variable `keys`, Python still knows that `keys` is associated with the original dictionary, so when we add a new element to `d` it invalidates the iteration.

One easy way to fix this may be to use `list()` to convert `keys()` to a simple list. Then you would be iterating over that list instead of the original dictionary, and modifying the dictionary would not invalidate the iteration. (Of course the iteration would not touch the new elements you add in this case.) Here's an example:

```
>>> d = { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B' }
>>> for k in list(d.keys()):
...     print( k )
...     if k == 'a':
...         d['c'] = 'C'
...
a
b
>>> d
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

Below is how it might look in your code. I'll also show you a trick to make the code simpler and easier to read. Instead of referencing `self.enemydict[key]` over and over, save it once in a variable called `enemy` and then use that.

So where the first part of the loop looks like this:

```
keys = self.enemydict.keys()
for key in keys:
    leap = self.enemydict[key].leap
    if self.enemydict[key].attacked == False:
        self.enemydict[key].counter -= 1
    if self.enemydict[key].counter <= 0 and self.enemydict[key].attacked == False:
        self.enemydict[key].counter = self.enemydict[key].turncount
```

It would be this:

```
for key in list(self.enemydict.keys()):
    enemy = self.enemydict[key]
    leap = enemy.leap
    if enemy.attacked == False:
        enemy.counter -= 1
    if enemy.counter <= 0 and enemy.attacked == False:
        enemy.counter = enemy.turncount
```

There's a place later in the loop where you could make a similar change, from:

```
                self.enemydict[(goingTo[0], goingTo[1])] = self.enemydict[key]
                self.enemydict[key] = ' '
```

to:

```
                self.enemydict[(goingTo[0], goingTo[1])] = enemy
                self.enemydict[key] = ' '
```

But note that I only changed the first of those two lines. I didn't change the second line to:

```
                enemy = ' '
```

That would not do the same thing as the original code. Instead of updating or adding a value in `self.enemydict`, it would change the `enemy` variable so it is no longer a reference to `self.enemydict[key]`.

This isn't a problem when you do things like:

```
        enemy.counter = enemy.turncount
```

because we're not changing the `enemy` variable itself, only the `.counter` property. `enemy` continues to refer to the dictionary entry.